# Showing Report with today's date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have Field  `Booking_DateTime` and in it we have like `2015-09-07 16:00:47`
Now the problem is , I want todays report, and the query will be like

```
select * from table where Booking_DateTime = 2015-09-07
```

But it doesn't shows me any data because I have date with time.. Now what should I do

Comment: Is the full stop in the end of your query part of your my sql statement or it was placed by mistake? I think the query is correct and working properly after removing the .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `DATE`.

```
select * from table where DATE(Booking_DateTime) = '2015-09-07'
```

Or event you don't have to set the manually if if you need the current date. Just do -

```
select * from table where DATE(Booking_DateTime) = CURDATE()
```